# Difference between phase and grain in a material

Tags: material-science

I couldnt get a good explanation differentiating phase and grain.From what I understood, a collection of unit cells arranged in the same orientation is called grain.A collection of grains with similar structure is called phase.Is this interpretation right?

Answer (score 2):

a phase is one particular stochiometry and crystallographic structure of the elements comprising a solid- for example in the iron-carbon system,  cementite, ferrite and austenite are all distinct phases.

Adjacent grains within a given phase have their crystallographic axies randomly oriented, but they all share that particular elemental composition and unit cell structure.

Comment: Thank you for answering.So in a phase, the propotion of the two components(in this case iron and carbon) and the crystallographic structure(FCC,BCC,etc..) will be the same through out the phase.But in a grain the orientation of the unit cells will also be the same.Is this right? Please suggest me some website or other resources where I could learn the basics of material science in detail in an order(I tried the book by William D Callister, but I couldnt really understand the concepts).

Comment: "Phase" refers to the chemical composition and unit cell of a substance. "grain" refers to the microscale structure of the phase. recommend you get hold of Van Vlack (an older text, but very good) or Shackelford (newer book, written by my thesis advisor at UC Davis).